# Why is the Visual Studio compiler saying I'm missing a semicolon in my C++ function?

Tags: c++, macros

Here's my function. The width and height variables are global integer variables defined above this function with values in the hundreds.

```
#define ORIGINAL_WIDTH 800;
#define ORIGINAL_HEIGHT 700;

void set_perspective(void) {
  int view_width, view_height;
  if (width < height) {
    view_width = width;
    view_height = (float) width * ORIGINAL_HEIGHT / ORIGINAL_WIDTH;
  }
  else {
    view_width = (float) height * ORIGINAL_WIDTH / ORIGINAL_HEIGHT;
    view_height = height;
  }
}
```

My C++ compiler notes "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '/'" on the lines:

```
view_height = (float) width * ORIGINAL_HEIGHT / ORIGINAL_WIDTH;
and 
view_width = (float) height * ORIGINAL_WIDTH / ORIGINAL_HEIGHT;
```

Does this have to do with casting? Why am missing a semicolon somewhere? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ironically, the compiler complains of a "missing ';'" because you have an extra ';' that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Not sure I would tag this C++?

Comment: @AJG85: I think pretty obviously it should be tagged C++ if the questioner is using a C++ compiler, or C if a C compiler. Not both, I agree, but I suppose when Andy added the "C" tag it was on the basis that the same question *could* be asked of C, with the same answer.

Comment: The original tag was exclusively "C++", and the error message C2143 confirms it.  I added "C" and "macros" to accurately help future indexing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eschew macros (which are text substitutions) and use constants, and this problem can't happen.

```
static const int ORIGINAL_HEIGHT = 800;
static const int ORIGINAL_WIDTH = 700;
```

Comment: avoiding globals altogether isn't a bad idea but I highly suspect we aren't looking at actual code as the compiler optimize this entire method out of existence.

Comment: The purpose to 'static' was to keep it in only this compilation unit, and from becoming global.  Even though the question was originally tagged C++, I opted not to use the anonymous namespace technique for hiding the symbol from the linker for potential external collision. ^^

Comment: @Andy: since you added the C tag for future indexing, it's probably slightly worth noting that in C, with macros `Pixel bitmap[ORIGINAL_WIDTH][ORIGINAL_HEIGHT];` is allowed at file scope or in a struct, but with `static const int` variables it is not, because a `const int` with visible definition is an integer constant expression in C++ but not in C. The `const int` are OK as array dimensions in function scope, but you get a VLA. This doesn't affect C++, only C.

Comment: Thanks Steve... I learned something new today.  I've removed the "C" tag.

Answer (score 13):

This is because you have semicolons in your `#define`. This is how it should look:

```
#define ORIGINAL_WIDTH 800
#define ORIGINAL_HEIGHT 700
```

`#define` does a literal text substitution, so your line looks like this to the compiler:

view_height = (float) width * 800; / 700;;